Motion model + IMU?
In the kalman filter framework, how do you incorporate both an IMU and a motion model?
Normally you use the IMU for stage propagation but I don't see why you can't use both?

Kalman Filter works with prediction and correction steps.

Prediction: Prediction step uses a model to estimate system's future state. Motion model comes on here. Motion model predics how state will evolve over time based on current state (your vehicle) and control inputs (wheel speeds, forces, etc.)
Correction: On correction step corrects the esimated states with covariance value.

You can use both the IMU and the motion model in the Kalman Filter for the prediction step. However, the IMU alone may not provide enough information for the correction step due to sensor noise and drift. To improve accuracy, you can add additional sensors like GPS to your system, which can provide more reliable measurements for the correction step.

Ok so how would you use both at the same time?

Here, there is a tutorial about Kalman Filter. I think you can start here. After that there are a lot of repo about Kalman Filter on github.
https://www.mathworks.com/videos/understanding-kalman-filters-part-1-why-use-kalman-filters--1485813028675.html

https://github.com/AtsushiSakai/PythonRobotics this repo is good for learning.
